# How to check two string conditions in SQL

Tags: sql

When I am writing the following query:

```
select *
from tablename 
where cloumn1 = "String1" 
  and column2 = "String2";
```

I get an error

> String2 : invalid identifier.

Comment: Have you tried single quotes ?

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Single quotes helped thanks causita

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Remove double quote

like this

```
select *
from tablename 
where cloumn1 = 'String1' 
  and column2 = 'String2';
```